# PHP Mobile Detect Load Separate Stylesheets

Tags: php, mobile

I'm using the script found [here](https://github.com/serbanghita/mobile-detect) to load a stylesheet depending on if it is a desktop, tablet, or phone.

The idea is for the desktop and tablet to have the same stylesheet, but for phones to load a seperate one.

The detection script is a few hundred(maybe thousand) lines long so for it, it's in the link, but the code I have written to load seperate styles is this:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/mobiledetect.php');
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

if($detect->isTablet()) {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/style.css">'."\r\n";
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/notification.css">'."\r\n";
}
if ($detect->isMobile()) {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/m.style.css">'."\r\n";
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/m.notification.css">'."\r\n";
}
else {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/style.css">'."\r\n";
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/notification.css">'."\r\n";
}
```

For some reason the phones work fine, but the tablet is loading both style sheets.

I tried putting the phone lines before the tablet ones, but then phones started loading the normal stylesheet instead of the mobile one, but the tablet was working fine.

I'd like to stick to using PHP for this because I plan on adding variables inside of the detection to also change other items such as titles and such.

Comment: `else if ($detect->isMobile()) {`

Comment: Do `else if` then only one condition can be meet.

Comment: Ah figures such  a simple solution lol. Thanks Steve.

Comment: Chris that explains a lot. I didn't know that it made it to where only one condition can be met. When I had mobile first I had an `else if` for tablet and since tablet wasn't working I figured that `else` just didn't need to be in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an else if because a tablet is also considered mobile. Try this:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/mobiledetect.php');
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

if($detect->isTablet()) {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/style.css">'."\r\n";
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/notification.css">'."\r\n";
} else if ($detect->isMobile()) {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/m.style.css">'."\r\n";
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/m.notification.css">'."\r\n";
} else {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/style.css">'."\r\n";
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/notification.css">'."\r\n";
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you did here? and for future visitors to the question/answer.